# Configuring app sandbox in Xcode 4 under Snow Leopard

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, app-store

Is it possible to configure Mac App Store application sandboxing if I'm using Xcode 4 + Snow Leopard? I'm reading the guide by Apple but I don't see anything about entitlements in the summary tab. Does this mean that all MAS developers will need to build their app on Lion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best way to go was to install Lion and use Xcode 4.3 or up. You will need to look for messages from `sandboxd` in the Console app to be able to catch sandbox violations and add the appropriate entitlements. AFAIK, this workflow wont work on Snow Leopard as `sandboxd` is not available.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an authoritative answer but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8677216/900693) leads me to think that XCode 4.2  is required to get these features. My XCode certainly didn't upgrade automatically to 4.2 but [the 2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8677216/900693) provides a torrent download link for XCode 4.2.

Here is a [link to using sandbox in SL](http://blog.loudhush.ro/2010/01/using-snow-leopard-sandbox.html).

Comment: I am running Xcode 4.2, but the relevant UI items to set entitlements isn't there, which makes me think that in March everyone who publishes to MAS must develop on Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Security entitlements are passed to the codesign command line tool during the build process.  I just tested building a "Developer ID" application on Snow Leopard with sandbox entitlements.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I also try on snow leopard with xcode 4.2 .It didn't provide any option of entitlements.
But on lion its perfect.And I think there is no alternative other than compiling on it lion OS.